# How to remove a node in CTREE

Tags: ida, idapython

Im learning about CTREE in IDA. Here is my ida decompiled code:

```
v3 = 0;
  if ( !strcmp(Str1, "hello") )
    v3 = 100;
  return a1 + v3;
```

At this time, i just want to mess arround with CTREE so I look at CTREE in graph for strcmp instruction (highlighted in pic). I notice that i need to remove **lnot** and replace it with something else.

[image: CTREE]

So my idea is create a new cexpr_t, use replace_by. But after that, i need to set cif.expr.x and for next block. But when i run the script, i got this error:

```
    raise Exception("%s is already owned, and cannot be reused" % v)
Exception: <ida_hexrays.cexpr_t; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'cexpr_t *' at 0x0000025277D9D300> > is already owned, and cannot be reused
```

So how can i replace the **lnot** block and still able to go to the call block. Here is my script:

```
from ida_hexrays import *
from idaapi import *

class Ctree_Test(ctree_visitor_t):
    def __init__(self):
        ctree_visitor_t.__init__(self, CV_FAST | CV_INSNS)

    def visit_insn(self,i):
        if i.op != cit_if:
            return 0
        
        cif = i.cif
        temp = cif.expr.x #get next block
        # create new expr
        x = cexpr_t()
        x.op = cot_bnot # just want to set it to bnot for testing
        x.ea = cif.expr.ea
        
        cif.expr.replace_by(x)
        cif.expr.x = temp # set next block

        return 0

function = get_func(0x401000)
decompiled_function = decompile(function)
se_2 = Ctree_Test()
se_2.apply_to(decompiled_function.body, None)
print("Done")
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Can you more clearly state your goal here? Are you trying to replace `!strcmp(Str1, "hello")` with `strcmp(Str1,"hello")`?

Comment: @RolfRolles the code i show on the question is just a poc (i just want to change the lnot node to something else like bnot). But my main goal is make `!strcmp(Str1, "hello")` to `strcmp(Str1,"hello") == 0`

Comment: So you want to patch the code? That's all? Or is this for educational purposes and you really want to know about Ctree and this is your exercise? Because I feel like there are easier ways to achieve a mere patch ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L yes, this is for educational purposes. i just want to start at ctree then microcode.